# Durandal compose change value of a variable of bound viewmodel

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal, durandal-2.0

In my app, I have a section called 'notifications' inside a view, called `'home.html'`. Now I need to use this section in another view, so I copied all the notifications markup inside 'notifications.html', that I'm using through composition.

The problem is that I don't want to copy all the code that I use for the notifications to work from 'home.js' to the another viewmodel of my new view that is going to use notifications. So instead of having an `observableArray` of notifications inside the view viewmodel, I want to have a module only for 'notification.html' that contains this data. But I don't know how I can change the value of the `observableArray` inside 'notification.js' from my other viewmodels.

Here is what I did so far:

notification.js

```
define(['knockout'], function(ko) {

var notifications = ko.observableArray([]),
setNotifications = function(data) {
    notifications(data)
}

return {
  notifications: notifications,
  setNotifications: setNotifications
}
```

home.js

```
define(['knockout', 'notification'], function(ko, notification) {
  var self = this
  ...
  self.activate = function() {
    http.get('...').then(function(data) {
    notification.setNotification(data)
  })
}
```

home.html

```
<div data-bind="compose: 'viewmodels/notifications'"></div>
```

What I know is that when using a viewmodel path in the compose binding, the markup of that viewmodel is injected and is bound to it's module viewmodel.

The problem: I want to change the value of the 'notifications' array inside `'notification.js'` from the viewmodel of my main view, `'home.js'`. I know that my current tentative isn't going to work, because I believe that the instance of `notifications.js` viewmodel being injected into `notifications.html` isn't the same instance that I require inside `home.js`. So how can I achieve that?

Comment: Would you like notifications to work as a singleton? So the same data should be displayed everywhere that the notifications view is displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this problem using the `model` property on the `compose` binding.

Markup:

```
<div data-bind="compose: { view: 'views/notifications', model: $root.notificationModel }"></div>
```

notification.js has the same code - it returns the viewmodel ("return vm")

And in the home.js file:

```
define(['knockout', 'plugins/http', 'notification'], function(ko, http, NotificationModel) {
 var self = this
 self.notificationModel;
 ...
 self.activate = function() {
  return http.get('').then(function(data) {
   self.notificationModel = new NotificationModel()
   self.notificationModel.setNotifications(data)
   })
 }

})
```